# What is use of this -f in this statement?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am not getting the use of `-f` from this statement in this program.

```
if [ -f $file ]
```

I got `if` but why we use `-f` here?

Here is whole program:

```
case $ch in
  1)
    echo -e "\n This is File Create Operation"
    echo -e "\n Please Enter File Name:"
    read file

    if [ -f $file ]
    then
      echo -e "\n File already existing!!!"
    else

      touch $file
      echo -e "\n File Created!!!"
      echo -e "\n Created File can be Checked From Following Table"
      ls -t|head -n 15
    fi
  ;;
```

Comment: `-f` checks whether the file exists (and it is a regular file)

Comment: @Cheery No, `-f` tests if the file is a regular file.  `-e` tests for existence.  http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html

Comment: @BaconBits [`-f` tests *both* the existence and the regular-ness of the file](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html).

Comment: Are you using bash? If so, `info bash` will show you the documentation for the shell. `[` is a built-in command, and `-f` is one of its options. An aside: Why are you printing newlines at the *beginning* of each line?

Comment: [Here](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=%5B+-f+%24file+%5D) is a handy tool for this type of question.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: `[` *is* a bash builtin. Try typing `type -a [` at a bash prompt. The output on my system is two lines: `[ is a shell builtin` and `[ is /usr/bin/[`. `which` is a separate command that doesn't know about bash builtins.

Comment: @KeithThompson It seems you are correct, and `which` in bash behaves different from what I'm used to in zsh & tcsh. Thank you for correcting me.

Answer (score 6):

`[` is usually both an alias to `test` and a shell builtin. `[ something ]` is equivalent to `test something`

See `help [` in bash to learn the bash builtin's version, and `man test` to learn about the non-builtin binary `/bin/test`.

you'll see that `[ -f file ]` is true if file exist and is a regular file, and false otherwise (ie it returns 0 only if `file` is a regular file)

Comment: to the downvoters, please tell me why you downvote? I think I answer the question?

Comment: Don't care about the downvoters. The number of high-reputation trolls are increasing on SO... +1 from me. ;) Just be sure than your answer is correct and also it answers the question. (now not fully - the OP asking about the `-f`)

Comment: The downvotes were *probably* because your original answer was incorrect about the closing `]`. While corrected, most people don't go back to post the downvoted when they're updated (you don't get a notification about this), so the downvotes stay. I don't think these are "troll" as @jm666 says, but were *valid at the time*...

Comment: @jm666: thx, I actually realised that I forgot to mention -f after I posted my question to downvoters (and I realise it was probably their reason to downvote), so I edited it just afterwards ^^

Comment: @Carpetsmoker ok, was my fault, not checed the edit history - i saw the answer when it was (nearly) correct. applogize to all non-trolls ;) :)